# Solr 3.6 : Changing date boosting based on seasons/months - is it possible?

Tags: date, solr

I'm having a kind of new solr 3.6 master/slave scenario running for the company I work for with a standard-boosting for newer docs (the all well-known recip-stuff) which works all fine. I do have several years of solr/lucene-experience myself, so I generally know how to set up things and get'em on track....
..but as of recently there's a new customer requirement where docs are to be dynamically boosted based on their 'month' of creation, having years come in second! so, whenever I do a search in February, boom, February-born documents come first...

The reason behind that is that there are all-time valid articles (say, regarding "summer home improvements" or "christmas cakes") that are to displayed in preference to others whenever I use the search during summer, winter or whatever.

How would I implement such behaviour? Any ideas, suggestions? I'm a little lost for the moment :) I could think of some black magic index-extra-info stuff but taking into account the usual date-based boosting I've no clue of how to approach this best.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a separate field for month and season and have a higher boost for this field.
This can be done at indexing time.

So when the user searches for such phrases these documents would come on top.

Comment: the problem is that the desired logics do not contain searching for a months or seasons themselves but rather to do a search for "meat" in early December and woosh, December-created documents come first in this month whereas the very same search in mid-July yields only fresh'n'lite summer recipes... but of course, I could do a basic monthly re-build of the entire index, boosting whatever documents are now in focus, month-wise